# NuGet Package reference issue: Sitecore.Serilog.Framework.Logging

Tags: nuget, sitecore-commerce

Is anyone out there using the `Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 CTP 3 release VM`?  I am having a `NuGet Package` reference issue in the `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Sample` project wondering if anyone has gotten past this:

```
Error: Unable to resolve 'Sitecore.Serilog.Framework.Logging (>= 1.0.0-alpha7-1019)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.
```

Comment: What exact action of yours results in the error? Does it happen during the build, or?..

Comment: it happens during the build, it also happens if I try and manually install the packages from package manager or when I tried to use the nuget.exe restore as suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer was to remove this NuGet packaged manually by editing the project.json file.  Apparently this package is not needed by the solution so removing it was safe.  There must be an issue with the package because even when I readded it from NuGet it still errored.  Something Sitecore will need to fix.

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue with restoring NuGet packages:

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3199

Currently, there seem to be at least two ways to "fix" it (kind of) that work with varying success rates:

- Restore packages manually using Visual Studio's context menu for your projects;
- Use [**NuGet 3.5 RC1**](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) and restore the packages using the command line: `nuget restore`.

Comment: So i have tried both of these and keep getting the exact same message.

Unable to resolve 'Sitecore.Serilog.Framework.Logging (>= 1.0.0-alpha7-1019)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.

I have also reached out to the Sitecore Commerce team but no response yet.